# aws elasticbeanstalk unexpected error 0000000001?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to setup amazon beanstalk with github and codebuild. So far the build works but when it gets to the deploy to amazon beanstalk i get an error. i cant solve it....
It uploads the artifacts to S3 but i get an error from the deploy of the elastic beanstalk. I have added the file codebuild uses appspec.yml to run the build, my elasticbeanstalk config, compose-local.sh config and at last the error i get from my aws pipeline i've setup that should deploy this to an ec2..

Any thoughts about this issue is appreciated. I am super stuck. thanks in advance.

my appspec.yml file used by codebuild:

```
version: 0.2

eb_codebuild_settings:
  CodeBuildServiceRole: arn:aws:iam::xxx
  ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
  Image: docker_image/root:production
  Timeout: 10
  #timeout is in min.

phases:
  install:
    commands:
        - echo "installing"
        - yum repolist
        - yum-config-manager --enable *addons
        - sudo yum update -y
        - sudo yum install docker -y
        - sudo service docker start
        - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose 
        - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        - docker-compose -v

        - echo Build started on `date`
  build:
    commands:
        - bash compose-local.sh
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "done"

artifacts:
  files:
    - '*'
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```

My .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: root-env
environment-defaults:
  root-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: root
  default_ec2_keyname: defaultkey
  default_platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: eu-central-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

compose-local.sh file

```
docker build --tag default:production --force-rm --file=webserver_dockerfile .
```

My execution error:

```
Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-x'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-x] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
```

Comment: Can you clarify what are you doing? "appspec.yml file used by codebuild" - codebuild use buildspec.yml, while appspec.yml is for codedeploy.

Comment: Yeah, but i've changed the buildspec.yml file from the mentioned to appspec.yml - it's possible with the current codepipeline at aws - if you see anything else odd with this code please mention.